# Is it possible to use older versions of angular 2 with ng2-webpack or angular-cli?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm finding very little information on how to use either of this generators, and one of the few things I have gathered is that it creates the base files for newer versions of *angular 2*,

more specifically I have the beta *v8* version so imports with `@angular` and such won't work.

Is it possible to make an older project compatible with this tools ? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is always recommended to use latest version of angular2. Because you know, There is always a chance that your older version code will be deprecated(surely will). As an example, `Angular2-router` and `Angular2-form`, They have changed a lot in their new version.

And now, answer to your question is - You can do it easily in angular-cli based project. You just need to open `package.json` and change the angular versions under `dependencies`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    ................................
    }
```

and then do a `ng build`. That would do :)